# Casting date to varchar in mysql throws syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar

Why does MYSQL throw the following error on this simple query

```
select
  cast(cast(ts as DATE) as varchar)
from
  table_name
limit
  1;
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'varchar) from table_name limit 1' at line 2

Comment: So don't do it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CAST() and CONVERT() functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) don't support VARCHAR as a type.

They supports BINARY, CHAR, DATE, DATETIME, DECIMAL, DOUBLE, FLOAT, JSON, NCHAR, REAL, SIGNED [INTEGER], TIME, UNSIGNED [INTEGER]. See the manual.

You shouldn't have to cast a DATE to a string type anyway. In many client interfaces, it'll become a string in the result set.

Some interfaces may convert to language-specific types, like `java.sql.Date`.